# https only working with localhost using thin server (ssl)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, localhost, thin

I am trying to run my ruby on rails project for testing purpose using the following URL:

```
https://systemipaddress:3000
```

But the above doesn't work. It seems that it works only for localhost

How can I counter this issue because I also want to run my project on remote machines using SSL encryption.

I have followed the following documentation to perform SSL:

http://silaror.blogspot.in/2013/05/running-rails-server-to-support-ssl.html

I am using thin server to run my project on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Below links will be helpfull for you

```
http://www.railway.at/2013/02/12/using-ssl-in-your-local-rails-environment/
http://www.napcsweb.com/blog/2013/07/21/rails_ssl_simple_wa/
```

Comment: still it will not work for https://ip-address:3000, it only works for localhost. I have already gone through above websites.

Answer (score 0):

By just disabling the internet proxy settings it works with ip.

we can access our projects in remote machines

```
In ubuntu, set proxy settings to none and it will work with ip as well as we can access our project from remote machines
```